# Setting up ParseStarterProject without using XIB on iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm not a big fan of using xib and I want to begin a starter project with Parse programmatically. The starter project example they have seems to work only with the xib file attached, and the other examples either build on the starter project (with XIB), or like AnyPic, dive right into things I don't yet understand. Does anybody have the "starter project" with Parse without the xib?

This is my code that I've tried using, but fails (no idea why). I'm simply trying to set a UINav as the root view controller, and call in a PFQueryTable as its primary view.

AppDelegate.h

```
//  AppDelegate.h
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
//  AppDelegate.m
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

[Parse setApplicationId:@"myAppID" clientKey:@"myClientID"];
[PFUser enableAutomaticUser];
PFACL *defaultACL = [PFACL ACL];
[defaultACL setPublicReadAccess:YES];
[PFACL setDefaultACL:defaultACL withAccessForCurrentUser:YES];

PFQueryTableViewController *querytable = [[PFQueryTableViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:querytable];

self.window.rootViewController = navViewController;

return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application

@end
```

edit: When I run the application the simulator comes up with a black screen and then Xcode gives me this error:

```
You need to specify a parseClassName for the PFQueryTableViewController.
```

Comment: could you please explain what has failed

Comment: I edited my question to show the error

Comment: you need to check the constructor and the properties of PFQueryTableViewController to see if you need to set something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [PFQueryTableViewController](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQueryTableViewController.html) class defines two initializers :

```
– initWithStyle:className:
– initWithClassName:
```

Your error comes from your call to `[[PFQueryTableViewController alloc] init]`.

Although calling `-init` will not fail as it's an inherited method from the `UITableViewController` class, it is not enough to initialize a `PFQueryTableViewController` object. You need to set a Parse class name to it. It's really just calling instead:

```
PFQueryTableViewController *querytable = [[PFQueryTableViewController alloc] initWithClassName:@"MyParseClassName"];
```

Where `MyParseClassName` is *"The class name of the PFObjects that this table will display"*.

Comment: I kept looking at the documentation from Xcode (by holding down the "option" key) and I'm just now realizing that it's showing the class reference for UITableViewController, and not PFQueryTableViewController... If I had the sufficient reputation, I would up vote your answer. thank you